# Python pyodbc and Oracle SQL Invalid Number Error

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm connecting to an Oracle database via pyodbc and consistently get ORA-01722. Is there anyway I can read the data in as character or something else to process it in Python? I have read-only access to this data and can't seem to find a solution to avoid the error. Here's the code and errors I'm getting.

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('myconnectionstring')
data_cursor = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'

DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: Ungültige Zahl\n\x00\u07fe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00뿗耄
\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00껐1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00櫈߯
\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 (1722) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Troubleshooting this table, I have 8 columns with the following characteristics:

```
q = "SELECT column_name, data_type FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'my_table'"
td = con.execute(q)
cols = np.vstack([i for i in td])
cols

array([['A', 'VARCHAR2'],
       ['B', 'VARCHAR2'],
       ['C', 'NUMBER'],
       ['D', 'NUMBER'],
       ['E', 'NUMBER'],
       ['F', 'NUMBER'],
       ['G', 'NUMBER'],
       ['H', 'VARCHAR2']], dtype='<U11')
```

The errors come from columns `B`, `D`, `E`, and `F`, so I tried to read these individually using `TO_CHAR` without any luck.

```
def get_tab_col(table_name, col_name):
    q = "SELECT TO_CHAR({}) FROM {}".format(col_name, table_name)
    return con.execute(q)

data = {}
for c in cols[:, 0]:
    try:
        x = get_tab_col(table_name, c)
        data[c] = np.vstack([i for i in x])
    except Exception as e:
        print('{} fails'.format(c))

B fails
D fails
E fails
F fails
```

I'm not sure if this is a language issue with the system or something else. I'm seeing Chinese (?) characters in all of the error strings, but my machine (OS: Windows 7 Enterprise) is in German.

Any help to read this database would be greatly appreciated!